# OpenMPI, how can multiple clients connected to one server be one communication?

Tags: c++, c, mpi, openmpi

I want all the clients connected to the server can be one communication.
I have tried merge, but it just merge the intra-comm and one client, and the output is inter-comm which can't be the param of MPI_Comm_accept.

my server

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    MPI_Status status;
    char portname[MPI_MAX_PORT_NAME];
    MPI_Comm clients[10] ;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Info env = MPI_INFO_ENV;
    MPI_Info_set(env, "ompi_global_scope", "true");
    MPI_Open_port(env, portname);
    MPI_Publish_name("service",env,portname);
    int i = 0;
    MPI_Comm merge;
    while (true)
    {
        MPI_Comm_accept(portname, MPI_INFO_ENV, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &(clients[i])); 
        i++;
    }
    MPI_Close_port(portname);
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

my client

```
#include<mpi.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    MPI_Comm server;
    char portname[MPI_MAX_PORT_NAME];
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Info env = MPI_INFO_ENV;
    MPI_Lookup_name("service",env,portname);
    MPI_Comm_connect(portname, MPI_INFO_ENV, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &server);
    int rank, size;
    while (true)
    {
        sleep(3);
        MPI_Comm_rank(server, &rank);
        MPI_Comm_size(server, &size);
        cout<<"size:"<<size<<",rank"<<rank<<endl;
    }

    MPI_Comm_disconnect(&server);
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: Everytime a new client connects to the server, you will need to create an new intercomm with the server and the previously connected clients in the first group, and the newly connected client in the second group, and then merge it to get an intra-communicator.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ~, I found that function (MPI_Comm_accept) can only use MPI_COMM_SELF(if -np 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD is ok), or the function will be blocked(for example, the merged intra-communicator) even if the client tried to connect the same portname. So there is no way to do that the new client can get all previously connected clients?
Besides, in the <mpi.h>, OMPI_DECLSPEC  int MPI_Intercomm_merge(MPI_Comm intercomm, int high,MPI_Comm *newintercomm); I think the placeholder newintercomm is incorrect.

Comment: `MPI_Comm_accept()` is a collective over the calling communicator, so unless all the previously connected clients invokes it, you have to use `MPI_COMM_SELF`, and add some logic to create later the communicator with all the clients.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the incorrect argument name, i will fix that shortly! If you tell me your full name, I will make sure you get credited for reporting this.

Comment: I'm Yan Wu, I think your reply to my question is enough~

Comment: Thanks, I issued a pull request accordingly https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/pull/11712